# I am trying to use elastic search with logstash and kibana but im unable to run a logstash file?

Tags: java, python, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have installed elastic search,logstash and kibana successfully. I have also installed jdk. Elastic search is running on port 9200 properly I am trying to run the logstash.conf file it is giving me following error
[it is giving me following error[image]

This is the code i am trying to run[image]

and i am trying to run code with following Two commands
1)logstash -f logstash.py
2)logstash -e 'input{stdin{}}output{stdout{}}'

Comment: Please do not put screenshots of code or command line output on StackOverflow, just copy-paste the text and format them as code.

Answer (score 1):

According to this message, one instance of Logstash is already running and you are trying to start another one. It is not a big problem if they are completely separated from each other. But you are starting the 2nd instance that uses *the same* database as the 1st one.

If this was not your intention, then first stop the 1st instance before starting the 2nd one.

If you really need multiple instances simultaneously, configure them correspondingly: database, ports.

Comment: i am beginner so can you plz guide me , how can i stop the first instance before starting the 2nd one

Comment: @VishalBadhe: It depends on how started it. First, check the list of processes in Task Manager and, if you see it there, stop it. If you started it as a service, open the list of service, find it and stop it.

Comment: If you want to run more than one instance of logstash, you can start the other instance by declaring the path of the config pipeline file by using path.data variable and running the logstash process manually.

Comment: @Preyas: I believe this was not an intention to run multiple instances, but it was rather overlooked that another instance is running.

Answer (score 0):

You are already running 1 instance of logstash.
either restart your OS (that will stop all running processes) and then execute it again.

Another option is to use the CLI command:

- type in your CLI: `top` or `ps aux | grep logstash`
- find the PID of the logstash
- type: `kill -9 <logstash-pid>`

If you are running logstash as a service try running:

- `service logstash status` - to see if it is running.
- `service logstash stop` - to stop it and then.
- `service logstash start` - to start it again.